# Visual Studio 2010 crashes on start, reinstall doesn't solve the issue

Tags: windows-7, crash, visual-studio-2010

All of a sudden my Visual Studio 2010 which worked fine on Friday no longer can be opened crashing every time I try to start it.

The only program I installed on Friday was EMS DB Comparer but in the mean time I

- Uninstalled EMS DB Comparer, rebooted.
- Tried repairing VS 2010 and rebooted.
- Completely uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2010 and rebooted.
- Tried running VS 2010 with /SafeMode switch.
- Installed all the latest updates for VS 2010.

None of this helped and I'm left in a situation where the only other thing I can think of is to completely reinstall Windows 7 and all the programs which is a full days work so I'd like to ask for any other ideas before I do that.

BTW, my VS 2012 installation works fine but I really need VS 2010 to work as well.

Comment: VS2012 can handle .NET 4 solutions without a problem, I don't understand that comment.

Comment: Thanks, I know but I still need VS 2010 to work.

Comment: Open eventlog of Windows, look for the crash and post the details here.